# building jquery gallery, transitions are a little off

Tags: jquery, css

i've built this gallery that for the most part works. The problem is, when i click on the right arrow, my gallery item slides off screen to emptyness, then the next image just shows up (instead of the next image sliding with it). When you hit the left arrow it's the opposite, the gallery image instantly disappears and slides in the new one. Any idea as to what's going on? You can see what i'm talking about by going here: http://jsfiddle.net/grem28/dhUEc/

here's the js:

```
$(function(){

    var curImg = 0;

    $('#leftArrow a').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            if(curImg!=0){      
                curImg--;

                $('.image_reel').css('left','+=323px');

            }else{
                curImg = ($('.image_reel img').size()-1);
                $('.image_reel').css('left',-($('.image_reel img').width()*($('.image_reel img').size()-1)));
            }

    });

    $('#rightArrow a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()

            if(curImg==($('.image_reel img').size()-1)){
                    curImg = 0;

                $('.image_reel').css('left','0px');

            } else {
                curImg++;

                $('.image_reel').css('left','-=323px');
            }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `overflow: hidden` you can see what's actually happening:

http://jsfiddle.net/dhUEc/1/

The images are actually down below and only pop up once there is room for them to fit.  I would suggest removing the `float` from the images and adding `white-space: nowrap` to the image reel.  You may also want to add `font-size: 0` to remove all space between the images.

```
.image_reel {
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 0;
    /* ... */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dhUEc/3

Comment: I would also suggest calculating the `left` value rather than using `+=`.  clicking a button while mid-transition can throw things off when using `+=`.

Comment: @Damien did you look at the fiddle?  How is that worse?

Comment: i actually just experienced the mid-transition problem. I did check out your fiddle and it wasn't working for me. I resolved the issue though using the float. I added this after setting the var curImg....  $('.image_reel').css('width',$('.image_reel img').width()*($('.image_reel img').size()+1));

that calculates the width of the .image_reel.